# Получить индекс элемента, на который произведен клик на странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется следующая функция, которая выводит в консоль путь от элемента до body, при нажатии на любой элемент страницы.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        tree = e.path; // Сам путь (готовое свойство события)
        const index = tree.findIndex(item => (item.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'body'))
        console.log(tree.slice(0, index + 1)); // Выводим путь при клике до body
})
```

Как сделать так, чтобы, таких элементов несколько (в одном div два img например), то возвращался их порядковый номер (индекс), а так же, чтобы при наведении на любой элемент страницы, элемент выделялся (обводкой его границ допустим)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да просто

```
 alert(e.path.reverse().splice(3));
```

или

```
 alert(e.path.reverse().splice(3).reverse());
```

или

```
 alert(e.path.splice(0,e.path.length-3));
```

Как больше нравится.

Чтобы выделяло линией:

```
let selected; 
document.body.onmousemove = e => { 
  let { x, y } = e; 
  if(selected) selected.style.outline = '';
  selected = document.elementFromPoint(x,y);
  if(selected) selected.style.outline='1px solid red';
};
```

Comment: Я возможно не правильно описываю задачу, но ваш код выводит путь от нажатого элемента до боди допустим, но задача в том, что если элемент не единственный в своем роде, то надо так же его индекс вывести. Например, если у нас блок div в котором находятся еще 2 блока img, то при нажатии на второй, возвращался путь от него до боди + его индекс, то бишь 1, если же нажали на первый img, то 0

Comment: Ответ в прошлом вопросе с индексом выводит.

Comment: Черт его знает, почему не работало при первом встраивании, но теперь все отлично) Благодарю!!!

Comment: А не подскажите, как это можно скомковать так, чтобы отправить через POST ajax?

Comment: Запускать по нажатию кнопки мыши?

Comment: `fetch('http://localhost:3000/ajax', {method:'POST', body: longDataString})`

Comment: Не, отправлять отдельным скриптом

Comment: Ну это от данных зависит. Если объект простой `myObject={a: 1, b: ' 2 '};`, то можно передать `fetch('http://localhost:3000/ajax', {method:'POST', headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: JSON.stringify(myObject)});`